# How to pass an array to mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Form helper collection_check_boxes returns data as an array, but how to put it into mysql database (or into variable in the controller)?

In my controller I have

```
  def new
    @subjects = Subject.all
    @student = Student.new(:first_name => "First name", :last_name => "Last name", :birthdate => "Birthday", :email => "E-mail", :phone_number => "Phone number", :classes)
  end
  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    if @student.save
      redirect_to(students_path)
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end
  private
  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birthdate, :email, :phone_number, :classes)
  end
```

Form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :classes, Subject.all, :id, :subject %>
<%= f.submit("Create student") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Maybe `serialize` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Why are you passing an array? Aren't you using a separate table for `classes`?